# Cart Counter not updating when editing on cart page. I'm using "Bigcommerce for Wordpress" plugin

Tags: wordpress, bigcommerce

I'm getting this issue only on my cart page, but on the other page like the home page, if I try to add a product, the cart counter works fine. But when I'm on my cart page if I try to edit my cart items (ex. add or remove a product) cart counter not updating, but if I wait for about 1 minute then try to edit my cart items, cart counter suddenly works fine.

I have tried to disable caching on developer tools, I still get the cart counter not updating issue on my cart page. I also try to disable caching on my whole site still not works.

The cart items displaying on my cart page are shortcode of bigcommerce plugin:
`[bigcommerce_cart]`

Answer (score 0):

Version 3.11.0 of the [BigCommerce for WordPress plugin](https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/BigCommerce-for-WordPress) came out a few weeks ago and has some fixes specifically for that issue. Can you try it with the latest version? You can find the latest version of the plugin here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/bigcommerce/